# Combine a list of list by element in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 4 list show below.

```
list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

How do I create a list of list by element position so that the new list of list is as follows?

```
list2 = [['a', 'd', 'g', 'j'], ['b', 'e', 'h', 'k'], ['c', 'f', 'i', 'l']]
```

I tried using a for loop such as

```
res = []
for listing in list1:
    for i in list:
        res.append(i)
```

however it just created a single list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` with the `*` operator to zip all of the sublists together.  The resulting tuples will have the list contents you want, so just use `list()` to convert them into lists.

```
>>> list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
>>> [list(z) for z in zip(*list1)]
[['a', 'd', 'g', 'j'], ['b', 'e', 'h', 'k'], ['c', 'f', 'i', 'l']]
```